# Attaching Arduino TFT LCD screen to Pi 4 without soldering it on?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, soldering

Note: Already asked on raspberry stack-exchange. I was directed to this community instead.

So I have this product: https://learn.adafruit.com/2-8-tft-touch-shield/lcd-test

My goal is to connect it to the pi 4, without soldering it on. I plan to use it as a small screen to run raspberry or twister os. I found an article on how to attach the Arduino screen to a pi zero, though, that requires it to be soldered on. The last option I found was to buy an Arduino adapter to add on top of the pi (https://www.seeedstudio.com/Arduino-Adapter-For-Raspberry-Pi-p-2443.html) My only problem is that I don’t know if it will work. For example, lets say I do buy that adapter, will it display the operating system as soon as I turn it on?
Also I had an idea on connecting the Arduino wires ( [https://www.amazon.com/Elegoo-EL-CP-004-Multicolored-Breadboard-arduino/dp/B01EV70C78/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=arduino+cable&qid=1619709817&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EV70C78) ) to the pi board and the Arduino screen. Though, I wouldn’t know which pins connect to which.

*Am a new learner, so please forgive me for ignorance. I also don’t know which pins belong to which, and what to connect to what?*

Comment: The equivalent product is available for the Raspberry Pi: [Adafruit PiTFT Plus 320x240 2.8" TFT + Capacitive Touchscreen](https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-screens/products/adafruit-pitft-plus-320x240-2-8-tft-capacitive-touchscreen). It may well be cheaper in the end than fiddling around with various adapters.

Comment: I dont want to waste the screen i already do have...I rather spend the extra money and use it instead...But thanks for the ideaa

Comment: If you're going to be playing with electronics, a temperature-controlled soldering iron such as a KSGER T12 (I haven't used that one) with a small variety of tips is pretty much a requirement, and will last you for many years ;)

Comment: Also, will the adapter work with the screen right out of the box.(Which I probably think wont happen)

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thanks for the offer, but im trying not to use the soldering iron…Thanks for suggestion though

Comment: Not sure why you were directed here. If your question is how various pre-made this-and-that adapters for various hobbyist boards work, then this is the wrong place to ask. If your question is how to routine the various signals of a TFT with chip on class and some manner of connector, then it may be on-topic here. But again, if your TFT is actually some manner of pre-made computer product, this is the wrong place to ask too.